# C# which numeric type for a math application?

Tags: c#, .net, math, double, decimal

I write an interval analysis C# application so I have to handle very large or small numbers. I think double is a very good data type (because the floating-point arithmetic). User can define any functions where I can detect the numbers in it with the following regular expression:

```
([0-9]+)|([0-9]+.[0-9]+)
```

This is a vica-versa progress, the application calculates some data and I have to match regular expressions on the calculated data as well. My problem is that in some critical cases double uses scientific abbreviation such as 1E-9 for example but I want to use the format defined in the regular expression above. I think decimal is a good type for this kind of situations but common math functions use double input so I have to convert it everywhere.

Is there a good and efficient way to handle this?
(Sorry for my English).

Comment: Please show your original problem. I think you are overthinking the problem and there might be an easier solution.

Comment: Don't confuse number storing and representation with number formatting for output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`double` doesn't use any particular text format until you come to render it as a string. *Then* you can choose what to do by specifying either a [standard format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) or a [custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). So *tell it* what you want. A wide range of examples are displayed on [`double.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx)